# Audio Player Progress bar glitching

Tags: php, html

so im trying to figure out how to programm a audio player for my website project im making for fun. it works like intendet but the time bar is completely messed up. everytime i try to go to like the middle of the song or anywhere else it glitches and just goes to the beginning of the song and i do not understand why.
[heres the link to my website](https://fit-helped-cub.ngrok-free.app/music.html) for you to check out what i mean by glitching

i tried many things already like checking if i have anything duplicate and if not if maybe actually adding a dupe makes it work i tried diffrent kinds of code for the progress bar but it kept glitching and idk why
heres the code im using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home</title>
    <style>
.nav-container {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: left;
            align-items: left;
            background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            padding: 10px;
        }

        .nav-link {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: black;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            margin: 0 1px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-radius: 1px;
        }
        .nav-link:hover {
            background-color: #444;
        }

        .subfolder-link {
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 8px 16px;
            background-color: #236;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            border-radius: 1px;
            margin: 1px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<a href="home.html">
    <img src="img/logo.jpg" alt="Savekillqqp's Shares" width="35%" height="35%">
</a>
</header>
<hr>

<nav>
    <div class="nav-container">
        <a class="nav-link" href="home.html">Home</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="citra.html">Citra</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="music.html">Music</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="movies.html">Movies</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="https://discord.gg/Ta9aamS7">Discord</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="test.html">Hentai</a>
    </div>
</nav>
</hr>

<div class="custom-audio-controls">
    <img id="song-image" src="" alt="" width="150" height="150">
    <button id="previous">Previous</button>
    <button id="play-pause">Play</button>
    <button id="stop">Stop</button>
    <button id="next">Next</button>
    <div class="progress-container">
        <input type="range" id="progress-bar" value="0">
    </div>
</div>

<h2>Now Playing</h2>
<p id="now-playing">Select a song to play.</p>
<audio id="audio" style="display: none;" controls>
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<div class="song-container">
    <h2>Song List</h2>
    <ul id="song-list">


    </ul>
</div>



<script>
    const audio = document.getElementById('audio');
    const songList = document.getElementById('song-list');
    const nowPlaying = document.getElementById('now-playing');
    const progressBar = document.getElementById('progress-bar');
    const playPauseButton = document.getElementById('play-pause');
    const songImage = document.getElementById('song-image');
    const songs = [];
    
        // Declare and initialize isPlaying
        let isPlaying = false;

    // Initialize the current song index
    let currentSongIndex = 0;

// Debugging line to check the image paths
console.log(songs);

    // Function to stop the audio
function stopSong() {
    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0;
    isPlaying = false;
    playPauseButton.textContent = 'Play';
}

// Event listener for the "Stop" button
const stopButton = document.getElementById('stop');
stopButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    stopSong();
});

// Function to play the selected song
function playSong(songSrc, songTitle) {
    audio.src = songSrc;
    audio.play();

    // Set the image source based on the song title
    const songImage = document.getElementById('song-image');
    songImage.src = `img/${songTitle.toLowerCase()}.jpg`;
    songImage.alt = songTitle;
}
    // Function to go to the next song
function nextSong() {
    currentSongIndex = (currentSongIndex + 1) % songs.length;
    playSong(currentSongIndex);
}

// Function to go to the previous song
function previousSong() {
    currentSongIndex = (currentSongIndex - 1 + songs.length) % songs.length;
    playSong(currentSongIndex);
}

// Event listener for the "Previous" button
const previousButton = document.getElementById('previous');
previousButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('Previous button clicked'); // Add this line
    previousSong();
});

    // Function to go to the previous song
    function previousSong() {
        currentSongIndex = (currentSongIndex - 1 + songs.length) % songs.length;
        playSong(songs[currentSongIndex]);

// Update the song image source and alt text
songImage.src = `img/${songTitles[currentSongIndex].toLowerCase()}.jpg`;
songImage.alt = songTitles[currentSongIndex];
        nowPlaying.textContent = `Now Playing: ${songTitles[currentSongIndex]}`;
    }

// Event listener for the "Next" button
const nextButton = document.getElementById('next');
nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('Next button clicked'); // Add this line
    nextSong();
});

function nextSong() {
    currentSongIndex = (currentSongIndex + 1) % songs.length;
    playSong(songs[currentSongIndex]);

    // Update the song image and now playing text
    songImage.src = songImages[currentSongIndex];
    songImage.alt = songTitles[currentSongIndex];
    nowPlaying.textContent = `Now Playing: ${songTitles[currentSongIndex]}`;
}

       // Function to pause the audio
       function pauseSong() {
        audio.pause();
        isPlaying = false;
        playPauseButton.textContent = 'Play';
    }

      // Event listener for play/pause button
      playPauseButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (isPlaying) {
            pauseSong();
        } else {
            audio.play();
            isPlaying = true;
            playPauseButton.textContent = 'Pause';
        }
    });

    songList.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (e.target.tagName === 'LI' && e.target.getAttribute('data-src')) {
        const songSrc = e.target.getAttribute('data-src');
        const songImgSrc = e.target.getAttribute('data-img'); // Get the image source
        nowPlaying.textContent = `Now Playing: ${e.target.textContent}`;
        playSong(songSrc);
        songImage.src = songImgSrc; // Set the image source
        songImage.alt = e.target.textContent; // Set alt text for the image
    }
});

        // Event listener for updating the progress bar
        audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', () => {
        const currentTime = audio.currentTime;
        const duration = audio.duration;
        const progress = (currentTime / duration) * 100;
        progressBar.value = progress;
    });

    // Event listener for clicking on a song in the list
    songList.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        if (e.target.tagName === 'LI' && e.target.getAttribute('data-src')) {
            const songSrc = e.target.getAttribute('data-src');
            nowPlaying.textContent = `Now Playing: ${e.target.textContent}`;
            playSong(songSrc);
        }
    });

     // Event listener for seeking the audio when moving the progress bar
     progressBar.addEventListener('input', () => {
        const progressValue = progressBar.value;
        const duration = audio.duration;
        const seekTime = (progressValue / 100) * duration;
        audio.currentTime = seekTime;
    });

       // Event listener for when the audio ends
       audio.addEventListener('ended', () => {
        isPlaying = false;
        playPauseButton.textContent = 'Play';
        songImage.src = '';
        songImage.alt = '';
    });

// Fetch the list of songs from the PHP script
fetch('musictest.php')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(songsData => {
        // Store the fetched songs data in a variable
        const songs = songsData;

        // Populate the song list and player controls
        songs.forEach(song => {
            const listItem = document.createElement('li');
            listItem.textContent = song.title;
            listItem.setAttribute('data-src', song.path);
            songList.appendChild(listItem);

            listItem.addEventListener('click', () => {
    nowPlaying.textContent = `Now Playing: ${song.title}`;
    playSong(song.path, song.title); // Pass both song path and title
});
        });

        // Log the songs array here
        console.log(songs);
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));

// Event listener for when the audio ends
audio.addEventListener('ended', () => {
    isPlaying = false;
    playPauseButton.textContent = 'Play';
    songImage.src = '';
    songImage.alt = '';
    nextSong(); // Automatically play the next song when the current song ends
});

// Inside the fetch block where you populate the song list and player controls
songs.forEach(song => {
    const listItem = document.createElement('li');
    listItem.textContent = song.title;
    listItem.setAttribute('data-src', song.path);
    listItem.setAttribute('data-img', song.image); // Updated to use the image path
    songList.appendChild(listItem);

    listItem.addEventListener('click', () => {
        nowPlaying.textContent = `Now Playing: ${song.title}`;
        audio.src = song.path;
        audio.play();
        songImage.src = song.image; // Updated to use the image path
        songImage.alt = song.title;
    });
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tested your website and saw no glitch (with Firefox).
Which browser causes the glitch to happen?

Comment: The progress bar just buggs back to the beginning of the song when ever i try to change where in the song itself im in, for example i try going forward around a minute in the song and it just restarts. the browser im using is opera gx

Comment: Your link doesn't work anymore, thus I can't test it with Opera.

Comment: my apologies i had my pc in for repairs cause the gpu explodet on me after trying stable diffusion. it should be up now for about 2 days of testing

Comment: There is indeed a bug with all Chromium based browsers (Chrome, Opera, Edge) but it works in Firefox.

Comment: any idea how i could fix it?

Comment: I don't have access to your website anymore, but my guess is that the `audio.addEventListener('timeupdate'` and `progressBar.addEventListener('input'` are working against each other. You'll have to trace both event to understand what is happening. Maybe adding a timeout between the two could solve the issue.

Comment: i apologize for the website i normally turn the pc off at night since its in my room and its really hot where i live rn which isnt really good for the pc's thermals. anyways i appreciate it but even after i tried changing those it still seems to not work properly on opera. it used to work at the beginning but now it just doesnt im confused.